# How to play 3 videos from raw folder in same Activity on different Button clicks in Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller, surfaceholder, textureview

I have to play three videos on 3 different `Buttons` in same `Activity`.

My first video gets played and if I play another video the last screenshot like image comes in foreground and the current video is playing behind the screenshot like image of previous video.

Please help me I have asked this question before and given this http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/surface-view-playing-video solution but this not helpful for me..

I have tried of playing this video on different `Activity` and after the completion of the video it comes to the previous activity.
But it is not suitable for me according to my current code structure..

Comment: code structure? i can't see it...

Comment: Dear pskink, 
I have used audiotrack, audiorecord,most importantly timer and corresponding animation and if I press back button to close my application the app after completion of video the app gets crashed..
That's I want these Video to play in the same activity.

Comment: Add the code to your question.

Comment: Are you Abhijeet Tekade?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one video view in the activity and switch content to play while buttons are clicking.
Before starting video playback,just check whether video is playing or not
For videoview you can check those by

```
videoView.isPlaying()
```

If it is playing then stop and start with new video content which is loaded from raw.
So the idea is while clicking a button, check videoview is playing then stop and start, else just start.

Create a function like this

```
playVideo(String path)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    if(mVideoView.isPlaying())
     {
       mVideoView.stopPlayback();
     }
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

call this function in three button clicks with the three different paths.

Comment: Dear Jiju Induchoodan can you please elaborate or give me a snippet.
Actually I am playing another video after the completion of first video.

Comment: Please provide the existing code base so that i can check and fix

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Play_Video_File_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=124&aaid=144 I have gone through this tutorial here is only one button and one video I have 3 buttons ans three videos that's the difference

Comment: giving null pointer exception in       mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
and in PlayVideo(uriPathfood);

My uriPathfood is   final String uriPathfood = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.food_animation;

Comment: make sure the path is correct and the uri is not null

Answer (score 0):

```
vidRiver = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);


vidRiver.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));


vidRiver.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/APK/river.mp4");
```

or

```
vidRiver.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
            + "/" + R.raw.river));
    vidRiver.requestFocus();
    vidRiver.start();
    setContentView(vidRiver);

    vidRiver.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
}
```